# SQL maximum date on a workflow

Tags: sql

I have a workflow table that I would like to return a result of all the workflow information. At the same time, I would also like to create additional columns to categorize the type of application and the last date of the workflow as the application close date.

For example:

```
table name: Approval_Workflow

Key  ID   Status         Comment      timestamp   
001  e1f  submit         none         01/05/2016        
001  f64  in process     Review       01/06/2016  
001  2l5  return to user missing info 01/08/2016  
001  8n8  resubmit       none         01/10/2016  
001  gr0  approve        none         01/10/2016  
001  b3u  activated      none         01/15/2016  
002  nb9  submit         none         01/08/2016  
002  us1  in progress    Review       01/08/2016  
002  cs6  approve        none         01/08/2016  
002  yt2  activated      none         01/10/2016
```

I would like to get the result with additional columns showing

```
Key  ID   Status         Comment      timestamp   type       closedate
001  e1f  submit         none         01/05/2016  bad appl   01/15/2016      
001  f64  in process     Review       01/06/2016  bad appl   01/15/2016
001  2l5  return to user missing info 01/08/2016  bad appl   01/15/2016
001  8n8  resubmit       none         01/10/2016  bad appl   01/15/2016
001  gr0  approve        none         01/10/2016  bad appl   01/15/2016
001  b3u  activated      none         01/15/2016  bad appl   01/15/2016
002  nb9  submit         none         01/08/2016  good appl  01/10/2016
002  us1  in progress    Review       01/08/2016  good appl  01/10/2016
002  cs6  approve        none         01/08/2016  good appl  01/10/2016
002  yt2  activated      none         01/10/2016  good appl  01/10/2016
```

I linked the table to itself and successfully categorized the type of application. But when I tried to use the MAX() function to get the maximum date of the workflow, I keep getting the same date of each workflow date.
I also try to get the date where status in "activated" as the closedate but without success.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's type come from?

Comment: What database are you using?  What is the logic for the "type" column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ANSI standard window functions for this.  Assuming that a "return to user" signifies a bad application:

```
select awf.*,
       (case when sum(case when status = 'return to user' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by key) > 0
             then 'bad appl'
             else 'good appl'
        end) as type,
       max(timestamp) over (partition by key) as closeddate
from Approval_Workflow awf;
```

Note that `key`, `type`, and `timestamp` are keywords in many databases, so they are not the best names for columns.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! So over (partition by ...) does the trick. Thank you very very much!